# Delphi thread and query

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I must check one table every x ms if something new was added. Aplication must work 24/7. It's this code is Ok. I use thread. Also, vQuery.Close, can do without it.

```
try
  vQuery := TADQuery.Create(nil);
  vQuery.Connection := Connection;
  vQuery2 := TADQuery.Create(nil);
  vQuery2.Connection := Connection;      

  while not Terminated do
  begin
    Sleep(50);        
    vQuery.Open('select * my_table order by id');

    if vQuery.RecordCount > 0 then
    begin
      vQuery.First;  
      while not vQuery.Eof do
      begin
        // some code
        vQuery2.ExecSQL('delete from my_table where id = :id', [vID]);
        vQuery.Next;
      end;
      vQuery.Close;  // <- can do without it
    end;           
  end;
except
  on E: Exception do
  begin
    ThreadException := E;
    CustomThreadErrorDescription := Format('ERROR', [ThreadId]);
    Synchronize(LogThreadError);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: How can we help ? Could you [`edit your question`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22383134/edit) and elaborate your problem ?

Comment: Are you quite sure that polling is the best solution to your problem? Does your network admin know that you are going to do that to his/her network?

Comment: You certainly dont want to do `select * from my_table` just to see if any rows exist because that will pull the entire contents back.  Try `select count(some_column) from my_table` instead.  And I suspect your 50ms sleep is *far* too short.

Comment: @GrandmasterB, it is not just checking if any rows exist. The query is iterated if any rows exist.

Comment: @UweRaabe Ah, you're right.  Still, he doesnt need to be doing `select *` 20 times a second when he only needs an id.

Comment: Do you know the value of vID before your while() loop starts, or do you work it out in your "// some code" block?  What is your server back-end?

Comment: wouldn't it be better to setup a trigger for the table and then have it tell you when something has changed?

Comment: You really should not use delete for each record (since there are no condition to delete them all), use Truncate table instead

Answer (score 1):

This is a common polling technique, some optimizations you might consider:

- Increase your sleep to something a bit larger, 50ms is quite short.  If at all possible make it a configuration option so it can be adjusted up or down as needed.
- Rather than select ALL records, just select ONE record.  You can use a TOP 1 or LIMIT clause to reduce your operating set. From experience, if your table between processes ends up with thousands of records, you will pull the thousands of records down using more memory than what is needed since your processing and deleting one by one.
- re-factor your query and do work into a nested function (called ProcessOneRecord) that returns true if it performed an operation, false if there was nothing found.  Then you can rewrite the main part of your method to look something like the following:

`while not terminated do 
    begin
      sleep(iSleepAmount);
      repeat until (not ProcessOneRecord) or terminated;
    end;`